# How to read Entire Web.Config file and put it in a collection?

Tags: asp.net, collections, web-config, settings

Is it possible to read the entire contents of the web.config file and put it in some type of collection?

appSettings (which in turns has other settings key/values)
mailSettings (which in turns has other settings key/values)
system.web (which in turns has other settings key/values)

etc...

Answer (score 0):

The `WebConfigurationManager` should already contain a collection for `AppSettings` (or other sections).

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595323/1737862