# asp.net c# web app with active directory and windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication, intranet

i'm currently developing an intranet web app, with a homepage and several departmental pages, the web app is merely for viewing information so everyone will have the same privileges. i've reached a point that i must worry about the app's access and authentication, my company has an active directory with several groups that i can use, after searching for a while i got the following questions:

- in the webconfig file, i forced windows authentication and blocked users that are not authenticated (deny users = ?)
- i saw somewhere that i need several webconfig files, one for each page, is that so? how do it make each page connect to the corresponding webconfig?
- after looking at some examples i can't figure out my AD connection string (i'm currently on a development machine), our AD groups are on our domain controller, the physical location is "DCserver.company_name.local\city folder\groups"
- do i need to create a login page? i mean doesn't that kinda go against the point of having windows authentication?
- i don't need to manage anything within the AD, i simply want to read the groups and ensure that, for example, the marketing people only have access to the homepage and the marketing departmental page
- as i've mentioned up there, there will be no special special privileges, the user from, for example, marketing will be able to click everything within his departmental page

i'm sorry for all the questions, but i'm relatively new to c# and .net development

Answer (score 0):

Following are the answers to your latest set of questions:

-In the webconfig can i specify the groups that have access to each departmental page as well as the homepage? kinda like the following code, if so, i need my ldap connection string to be placed before assigning which groups have access to which page, right?

**[Dipra]** You are probably better off doing the authentication without using the roles in web.config, as this will also require the roles to be defined. We are talking about AD groups here, of which users will be a part. So, in the `Page_Load()`, simply call the authentication method, probably passing the username and the AD group allowed access to the page as parameters. If you want to make your solution configurable, store the allowed AD group for a particular page as 'keys' in your web.config and then read them in your code. Pass the group to your authentication method along with the username.

-when a user opens the web site, he will be prompted to insert his windows credentials, this is automatic, right? he will then be able to see the homepage and then go to his departmental page, right?

**[Dipra]** Yes, this is automatic. No separate code required for this. He can go to whichever page he wants, provided he is authenticated.

-if i understood correctly, in every page_load event i need to do a search taking the user's name and checking to which groups he belongs to, is that right?

**[Dipra]** Yes, you need to do that check in every `Page_Load()` method. As an approach, you can try getting all the groups of which the user is a part, and then check whether the allowed AD group for that page is one of those groups. If it is, the user can be authenticated.

-i the above is true, and now i'm gonna explain the navigation of the page 'cause i think that messing with the page_load might bring me some issues
will the check to see to which groups the user belongs to occur with every page load? won't that make the app slow?

**[Dipra]** Every server side control, e.g asp buttons, will cause a postback. To ensure the authentication code in `Page_Load()` doesn't run every time a postback happens on the page, enclose that bit in `if(!Page.IsPostBack) {}`. This means any code within this block will run when the page is not being 'posted back', i.e., being rendered for the first time. Any subsequent postbacks from server side controls on this page will ignore the code inside this block.

-finally, to check the membership of each user i need a similar code to the second answer on this [The Link that Dipra posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309988/how-to-get-the-groups-of-a-user-in-active-directory-c-asp-net) i pasted below but in c#, right?

**[Dipra]** You can refer to the accepted answer on the above post, probably with a couple of tweaks of your own. It's already in C#.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, your web.config would be like what you said.
2. You don't need to 'grant' access to specific groups for pages. In the web.config, store the groups allowed access to specific pages as keys and read the configuration in your code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595288/reading-a-key-from-the-web-config-using-configurationmanager). For example, if you have a `key` named 'Marketing', then you can store the name of the corresponding AD group, which is allowed access to Marketing pages in the `value` field. Yes, once you have got it working for one page, others will be easier.
3. No, the authentication method that I talked about is a custom method you will write for yourself, which will use logic similar to the one in the link I had posted.
4. The entire authentication code should be enclosed in a `try...catch` block. If there are issues while doing the authentication against your AD (for e.g., connection problems), then your code will throw an exception. Catch (and ideally log) the exception and redirect the user to an error page, probably saying there were some problems which prevented authentication. You should not be granting access to the user in such a scenario.