# Print the Remaining Session Time to View in Real-Time in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to show the remaining session time in `View` in real-time when logged in **ASP.NET MVC** project? I didn't add any code to the question because I didn't come across any solution during my research.

Comment: The way sessions work is any user action with the server is supposed to reset the session. So if you have, say, 20 minute sessions, at the time of any http request --that is, any C# code runs at all other than heartbeat/signalr stuff -- the session time remaining is **always** the full 20 minutes. So at this point what you're really doing is writing a javascript countdown timer for the amount of your session timeout.

Comment: I can set up a counter on login, but how can I share the counter value between different Views? In addition, the session duration can be changed via the **web.config** file.

Comment: If the session time gets reset with each action, there would be no value to share between views.  [Get value from web config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595323/1679220)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in 2 steps, first pass the timeout value using a partial, so it can be reused. For e.g. read it from your `Web.Config etc` and pass it.

Then inside your view, you can add this script and adapt/modify the values.

```
@functions {

    public int PopupShowDelay {
        get { return 60000 * (Session.Timeout - 1); }
    }

}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.SessionTimeout = (function() {
        var _timeLeft, _popupTimer, _countDownTimer;

        var stopTimers = function() {
            window.clearTimeout(_popupTimer);
            window.clearTimeout(_countDownTimer);
        };

        var updateCountDown = function() {
            var min = Math.floor(_timeLeft / 60);
            var sec = _timeLeft % 60;
            if(sec < 10)
                sec = "0" + sec;

            document.getElementById("CountDownHolder").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;

            if(_timeLeft > 0) {
                _timeLeft--;
                _countDownTimer = window.setTimeout(updateCountDown, 1000);
            } else  {
                window.location = "Home/TimeOutPage";
            }
        };

        var showPopup = function() {
            _timeLeft = 60;
            updateCountDown();
            ClientTimeoutPopup.Show();
        };

        var schedulePopup = function() {
            stopTimers();
            _popupTimer = window.setTimeout(showPopup, @PopupShowDelay);
        };

        var sendKeepAlive = function() {
            stopTimers();
            ClientTimeoutPopup.Hide();
            SessionTimeout.schedulePopup();
        };

        return {
            schedulePopup: schedulePopup,
            sendKeepAlive: sendKeepAlive
        };

    })();

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        A timeout warning popup will be shown every @(Session.Timeout - 1) min.
    </p>
    @Html.Partial("TimeoutPartial")
}
```